# Cannot see the content and image on the user control

Tags: windows-phone-7

I created the user control, I added them in the stackpanel by coding. when it is complier, there is no error. However, I didn't seen any content  and image on this user control. When the button is clicked, it open another page. I know the click event is working fine. Would someone show me how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.
The following is my UserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl  x:Name="NoButtonListItemControl"   
 x:Class="PhoneApp1.NobuttonListItem"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" > 
    <StackPanel  Margin="14,17,20,48" >             
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=PicFileName,      
              ElementName=NoButtonListItemControl}"    
                Width="120" Height="120"></Image>               
            <Button Content="{Binding Path=Description,  
           ElementName=NoButtonListItemControl }"  
                         ClickMode="Press"     
          Click="btnNoButtonListItem_Click" FontFamily="Georgia" 
         FontSize="15" Foreground="SkyBlue" Height="90" 
        Width="400" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID,  
         ElementName=NoButtonListItemControl }" 
          Style="{StaticResource pageTitleStyle}"
                       TextAlignment="{Binding}"     />

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The following is my UserControl.xaml.cs:

```
namespace PhoneApp1 
{
    public partial class NobuttonListItem : UserControl
    {
    public NobuttonListItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty PicFileNameProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("PicFileName", typeof(string), 
   typeof(NobuttonListItem), null);

    public static DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Description", typeof(string), 
  typeof(NobuttonListItem), null);

    public static DependencyProperty IDProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ID", typeof(string), 
    typeof(NobuttonListItem), null);

    public string PicFileName
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(PicFileNameProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PicFileNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(IDProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IDProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private void btnNoButtonListItem_Click(object sender, 
        RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Navigate(new 
         Uri(String.Format("/CallPage.xaml?ID={0}",ID), 
       UriKind.Relative));
    }


  }
```

}

There is test.xaml page in which I added the user control:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:my="clr-  
    namespace:PhoneApp1"  
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.test" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-
    namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-
    namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-
    compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" 
       Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" 
          Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,- 
         7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="spListPanel" Loaded="spListPanel_Loaded" 
     Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2"  Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

    </Grid>



 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The code behind of the test.xam l page:

```
namespace PhoneApp1
  {
    public partial class test : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
       public test()
       {
        InitializeComponent();            
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);

       }

       void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {


        ShowList();

     }
    void ShowList()
    {
        int userControlUniqueID = 0; 

        AddItem("1", "Test 1", "onHold_icon.png", 1);
        AddItem("2", "Test 2", "responded_icon.png",2);

    }


    void AddItem(string id, string description, string fileName, 
        int userControlUniqueID)
    {
        NobuttonListItem item = new NobuttonListItem();
        item.Name = "lst_" + Convert.ToString(userControlUniqueID);
        item.ID = id;
        item.Description = description;
        item.PicFileName = "/images" + "/" +fileName;
        spListPanel.Children.Add(item);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Run the app and check the Output window for Binding errors... I'm not sure, but I'll bet this has something to do with binding the Image Source property to a string type value...

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the following code in your "CodeBehind" file

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

If it still doesn't work, please post some of the output in the output window

Comment: If I placed teh this.DataContext=this; after the stament to call  "ShowList fuction". The output is txtUser is the property of  my isolated store . If I changed to this.spListPanel.DataContext = this, the member of this includes base, _contentLoaded, ApplicationTile, LayourRoot, PageTitle, spListPanel, TitlePanel which are the controls. I still don't know what's wrong with my queote.

Comment: place it before the show list function
then you do this.spListPanel.ItemsSource = myObservableCollection<MyClass>;